# Unicorn with Resque in Heroku - Should I be concerned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, unicorn

So far I am using the Thin server.  I am planning on switching to Unicorn to add some concurrency to the web dynos, and I am concerned because I read through [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) article and I found this code:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # ...
 
  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
  end
end
 
after_fork do |server, worker|
  # ...
 
  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = ENV['REDIS_URI']
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end
end
```

I don't really understand why is this code necessary and if I should add it or not when using Resque.

What do you guys think I should take into account when switching to Unicorn if I am using some Resque workers?

Answer (score 0):

Unicorn is a forking, multi-process server.  It loads your Rails environment in one process, then forks a number of workers.  Using `fork` causes it to copy the entire parent process, including any opened connections to databases, memcache, redis, etc.

To fix this, you should re-connect any live connections in the `after_fork` block as shown in the example.  You only need to reconnect connections/services you're using.